# Run Rsync from Python

Tags: python, curl, rsync

I need to run an rsync command from Python. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

```
rsync -Ccavz --delete DJStatic username@website
```

Comment: you can run shell commands from python http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html, also `fabric` provides a nice api that wraps many comman shell commands http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html

Comment: In 2017 there is now a pure-python rsync library :: [pyrsync](https://github.com/isislovecruft/pyrsync) (not a wrapper)

Comment: @philshem: It seems that repo hasn't been updated since 2013. What advantage does it offer vs. the system call?

Comment: I have written a very basic wrapper using system's rsync and pythons subprocess, providing some features like printing the progress etc for my own personal purposes: https://github.com/lfreist/PyRsync...

Answer (score 31):

You can call a subprocess from python using the following snippet

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

In your case, it would be something like this

```
subprocess.call(["rsync", "-Ccavz", "--delete","DJStatic", "username@website"])
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more details.

Comment: `subprocess.call("rsync -Ccavz --delete DJStatic username@website".split())` is slightly more readable and practical to type.

Comment: @jolvi if none of your arguments have spaces ...

Comment: Use `shlex.split(s)` instead of regular `s.split()` to split arguments up as a normal (POSIX) shell would.

Comment: @jolvi's version (passing command as string) should not be used!  Pass the arguments as a list of strings.  It will save you tons of time debugging later on when you can't figure out why your shell command isn't doing what you expect due to some quotes or spaces in a variable somewhere.  The tradeoff of saving 2-3 seconds of typing just isn't worth it

Comment: @Brandon: For those who don't have spaces in the command, that's totally fine, and it is easier. If there are spaces, that approach can be fixed using `shlex.split()` instead of `split()`, as mentioned by Chris L. Barnes. I think it's fine to use that solution if you do so cautiously. Unless...is there some other specific issue this causes?

Comment: @jvriesem you are 100% correct, using `shlex.split` solves the problem, as long as you ensure you always use it when passing a command as a string